# R expand.grid for repeated combinations of a vector in groups?

Tags: r, data.table, combinations, combinatorics

Been working on this for two days, and don't see any progress.
Say I have 20 numbers, and I want to (without replacement)

- get one unique group of 10 numbers
- get two unique groups of 3 numbers
- get two unique groups of 2 numbers

There are (20 choose 10) * (10 choose 3) * (7 choose 3) * (4 choose 2) * (2 choose 2) = 4,655,851,200 total groups.

I'd like either a nested list or a data.frame that I can evaluate these groups over.
Is that possible to do *quickly* in R?

Below I have a pretty unwieldy solution for the case when I'm just trying to get one unique group of 5, one unique group of 3, and one unique group of 2, from 10 numbers.

This code actually works, but quickly becomes untenable for larger groups.
I'm wondering if there's a fast way to create this grid?
It seems like it should be easily possible, but I can't figure out how.
Thanks in advance!!

```
library(data.table)
library(gtools)

n <- 10
group_sizes <- c(5,3,2)

# initialize first group
group_3_values <-
  combinations(
    n = n,
    r = group_sizes[1], # size of the first group!
    repeats.allowed = T,
    v = 1:n
  )
group_3_values <- as.data.table(group_3_values)
group_3_values[, row := 1:nrow(group_3_values)]
output <- as.data.table(group_3_values)

# run for loop for the remaining groups
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (group_size in group_sizes[-1]) { # size of the second, etc. groups
  output_list <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(output)) {
    remaining_options <-
      setdiff(1:n, output[row == i, .SD, .SDcols = !c('row')])
    second_group <- combinations(
      n = length(remaining_options),
      r = group_size,
      repeats.allowed = F,
      v = remaining_options
    )
    second_group <- as.data.table(second_group)
    second_group[, row := i]
    out <-
      merge(
        output[row == i,],
        second_group,
        by = "row",
        all.x = T,
        all.y = T,
        allow.cartesian = T
      )
    out$row <- NULL
    output_list[[i]] <- as.data.table(out)
    out <- NULL
  }
  output <- as.data.table(rbindlist(output_list))
  output[, row := 1:nrow(output)]
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
duration <- end_time - start_time
print(duration)
```

Comment: I am not understanding the goal.  Maybe provide a sample of the expected output. If you are looking to divide 20 numbers into 5 separate groups, why not use the `sample()` function to shuffle the initial groups and then divide into the groups of 10, 3, 3, 2, and 2.

Comment: @Dave2e The problem with that is that you will also get e.g. `[1, 2, ..., 10]`, `[2, 1, ..., 10]` for the first group, which is not unique.

Comment: There is a function in `RcppAlgos` called `comboGroups` that will partition a vector into groups of equal size. Your problem is similar and is something I've thought about for a while (I am the author). I always found it tricky to nail down whether the order of the groups by size matters. When all groups are the same size, you don't have this problem. What I mean is, can the first group be of size 3, or does it have to be of size 10? This changes things considerably. If order doesn't matter, you will be happy to know that the total is greatly reduced!

Comment: yes, order doesn't matter! But ignoring order should give you ~4m groups, no? e.g.  (20 choose 3) * (17 choose 10) * (7 choose 3) * (4 choose 2) * (2 choose 2) == (20 choose 10) * (10 choose 3) * (7 choose 3) * (4 choose 2) * (2 choose 2)

Comment: @Daycent, I think you meant 4 billion... Anyway, no, you will not get that many results since you have multiple groups of the same width. Consider a simple example where we want to get two groups of 2 from 4. Using your logic, we would get `choose(4, 2) * choose(2, 2) = 6` total results. If you write them out, you will see that the last 3 are duplicates of the first 3 only flipped around. So technically, for your example there would be `4655851200 / (1! * 2! * 2!) = 1163962800` total results.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57732672/4408538 for more information. There is some really good discussion in the answers and comments.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful Joseph. Thanks so much for your amazing work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think materializing a table or even a vector of 4,655,851,200 elements is not a good choice. Perhaps the best you can do is to use `combn` to generate each combination, with a callback to run your desired code.

This example generates and prints the elements for every combination and increases a counter `n` in the global scope. I use `callCC` for early exit at 10 iterations .

```
x <- 1:20

n<-0
callCC(function(exit)
  combn(x, 10, function(i)
    combn(setdiff(x, c(i)), 3, function(j)
      combn(setdiff(x, c(i,j)), 3, function(k)
        combn(setdiff(x, c(i,j,k)), 2, function(l)
          combn(setdiff(x, c(i,j,k,l)), 2, function(m){
            n<<-n+1
            # YOUR CODE HERE
            print(paste0(sapply(list(i,j,k,l,m), paste0, collapse=" "), collapse=" | "))
            if(n>=10) exit("early exit")
          }, simplify=F),
        simplify=F),
      simplify=F),
    simplify=F),
  simplify=F))

#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 17 18 | 19 20"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 17 19 | 18 20"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 17 20 | 18 19"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 18 19 | 17 20"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 18 20 | 17 19"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 16 | 19 20 | 17 18"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 17 | 16 18 | 19 20"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 17 | 16 19 | 18 20"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 17 | 16 20 | 18 19"
#> [1] "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 | 14 15 17 | 18 19 | 16 20"
#> [1] "early exit"
```

Comment: Nice, +1 I had a similar idea. Might be worth to use `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` which is much faster than `combn`.

Comment: Good point! I didn't know him.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very similar to [Create Combinations in R by Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57732672/4408538). The only difference is that the linked question required that each group be the same size. While this is a small change, it has massive implications from an algorithm standpoint.

As @Ric has pointed out, this is going to be difficult with respect to hardware and computation time.

Before we get started, it is important to note that there are actually `1,163,962,800` total results as the formula given by the OP doesn’t account for the order of the groups. As a small example, consider generating 2 groups of 2.

```
1 -> (1, 2) (3, 4)
2 -> (1, 3) (2, 4)
3 -> (1, 4) (2, 3)
4 -> (2, 3) (1, 4)  ## Same as 3, but the groups are permuted
5 -> (2, 4) (1, 3)  ## Same as 2, but the groups are permuted
6 -> (3, 4) (1, 2)  ## Same as 1, but the groups are permuted
```

In order to obtain the correct number, we must account for the groups of same size. In our example, we have 2 groups of 3 and 2 groups for 2, so we must divide our original result by `2! * 2! = 4`:

```r
(choose(20, 10) * choose(10, 3) *
    choose(7, 3) * choose(4, 2) *choose(2, 2)) /
(factorial(2) * factorial(2))
#> [1] 1163962800
```

It is great that we have reduced the size of our output, however we still are talking about greater than 1 billion results.

### Enter `RcppAlgos`

I am the author of the package `RcppAlgos` and as of version `2.8.0` we were able to handle partitions of groups of any size and as of `2.8.2` we could iterate over them via `comboGroupsIter`.

If your machine could handle it, we could pretty quickly generate all of the results with the function `comboGroups` using the parameter `nThreads` for producing results in parallel. Needless to say, you would need a decent chunk of memory:

```r
library(RcppAlgos)

desired_grps <- c(10, 3, 3, 2, 2)
v <- seq_len(sum(desired_grps))
comboGroupsCount(v, grpSizes = desired_grps)
#> [1] 1163962800

## If you really wanted to generate them all,
## you will need at least 87 GBs free. The formula used is:
## ((# rows) * (# columns) * (bytes per cell)) / (# bytes in Gibabyte)
(comboGroupsCount(v, grpSizes = desired_grps) * 20 * 4) / 2^30
#> [1] 86.72199
```

Alternatively, we could utilize the arguments `lower` and `upper` as we did in the answer to [Create Combinations in R by Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861934/4408538) to keep memory low, however this can get cumbersome.

A better option is to use iterators to keep memory low. These iterators are quite flexible, offering various methods for traversing the results and they even offer random access via `[[`:

```r
## nThreads is optional, however we choose 4 threads for increased efficiency
it <- comboGroupsIter(v, grpSizes = desired_grps, nThreads = 4)

## To see the next result, call the method nextIter
it@nextIter()
#> Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3 Grp4 Grp4 Grp4 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16 
#> Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>   17   18   19   20

## To see the next n results, call nextNIter
it@nextNIter(5)
#>      Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3 Grp4 Grp4 Grp4 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   11   10   12   13   14   15
#> [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   12   10   11   13   14   15
#> [3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   13   10   11   12   14   15
#> [4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   14   10   11   12   13   15
#> [5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   15   10   11   12   13   14
#>      Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5
#> [1,]   16   17   18   19   20
#> [2,]   16   17   18   19   20
#> [3,]   16   17   18   19   20
#> [4,]   16   17   18   19   20
#> [5,]   16   17   18   19   20

## Note, the state is updated
it@summary()
#> $description
#> [1] "Partition of v of length 20 into 5 groups of sizes: 2, 2, 3, 3, 10"
#> 
#> $currentIndex
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $totalResults
#> [1] 1163962800
#> 
#> $totalRemaining
#> [1] 1163962794

## Quickly jump to a specific point, m, without generating the m - 1 results before it
it[[1e8]]
#> Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3 Grp4 Grp4 Grp4 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>    1   10    3   12    5   14   19    6   18   20    2    4    7    8    9   11 
#> Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>   13   15   16   17

## Again, the state is updated
it@summary()
#> $description
#> [1] "Partition of v of length 20 into 5 groups of sizes: 2, 2, 3, 3, 10"
#> 
#> $currentIndex
#> [1] 100000000
#> 
#> $totalResults
#> [1] 1163962800
#> 
#> $totalRemaining
#> [1] 1063962800

## To see the last result
it@back()
#> Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3 Grp4 Grp4 Grp4 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>   17   20   18   19   11   15   16   12   13   14    1    2    3    4    5    6 
#> Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 Grp5 
#>    7    8    9   10
```

The algorithms are very efficient as well and can handle generating all `1,163,962,800` in a reasonable amount of time, especially when we use `nThreads`

```r
system.time({
    ## Reset the iterator
    it@startOver()

    ## Generate one million at a time
    while (!is.null(it@nextNIter(1e6))) {}
    print(it@summary())
})
#> $description
#> [1] "Partition of v of length 20 into 5 groups of sizes: 2, 2, 3, 3, 10"
#> 
#> $currentIndex
#> [1] 1163962801
#> 
#> $totalResults
#> [1] 1163962800
#> 
#> $totalRemaining
#> [1] -1
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  25.271   3.668   8.771
```

Not only were we able to iterate over all `1,163,962,800` results in under 10 seconds, we also kept our RAM happy by only requiring  `round((1e6 * 20 * 4) / 2^20) ~= 76` Megabytes per iteration.