# Creating result groups in R, using each element once (combination without repetition)

Tags: r, grouping, combinations, combn

I have a dataset of 6 individuals: A,B,C,D,E,F

I want to group these into two groups of three individuals and have done so with the combn function in R:

`m <- combn(n, 3)`

This gives me all 20 possible groups where individuals occur in multiple groups. From this set of groups I then went to find all possible combinations of results, where each individual can only be used once.

I would like to do this using combinations without repetition:
C(n,r) = n! / r!(n-r)! and would therefore get 10 results that would look like this:

- abc + def
- abd + cef
- abe + cdf
- abf + cde
- acd + bef
- ace + bdf
- acf + bde
- ade + bcf
- adf + bce
- aef + bcd

I am not sure how to code this in R, from the list of groups that I have generated.

Edit: to generate the dataset I am using I have used the following code:

```
individuals <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
n <- length(individuals)
x <- 3
comb = function(n, x) {
  factorial(n) / factorial(n-x) / factorial(x)
}
comb(n,x)
(m <- combn(n, 3)) 
numbers <- m
letters <- individuals
for (i in 1:length(numbers)) {
  m[i] <- letters[numbers[i]]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal and reproducible data set from which one could provide an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just now I am using a test dataset which I am generating as below:                                                                                                               
'individuals <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
n <- length(individuals)
x <- 3
comb = function(n, x) {
  factorial(n) / factorial(n-x) / factorial(x)
}
comb(n,x)
(m <- combn(n, 3)) 
numbers <- m
letters <- individuals
for (i in 1:length(numbers)) {
  m[i] <- letters[numbers[i]]
}'

Comment: Please add that to the question rather than in the comment seciton

Comment: I have added it to the question now!

Comment: What do you mean by `+` in your expected output? Are there values attached to each groups (e.g. "abc")?

Comment: I am expecting there to be 10 combinations of two groups as a result. So here the plus just represents the two groups that I would expect to get for that combination. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Combinations in R by Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732672/create-combinations-in-r-by-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

1. Create `combn`ations of 3 letters and store it in a list (`asplit`)
2. Create new `combn`ations of 2 groups (of 3 letters)
3. `Filter` the list to only keep combinations where the both parts have no element in common

```r
individuals <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
combn(individuals, 3, simplify = FALSE) |>
  combn(m = 2, simplify = FALSE) |>
  Filter(f = \(x) !any(x[[1]] %in% x[[2]]))
```

output

```r
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "d" "e" "f"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "d"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "c" "e" "f"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "e"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "c" "d" "f"


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "f"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] "c" "d" "e"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] "a" "c" "d"

[[5]][[2]]
[1] "b" "e" "f"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "a" "c" "e"

[[6]][[2]]
[1] "b" "d" "f"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
[1] "a" "c" "f"

[[7]][[2]]
[1] "b" "d" "e"


[[8]]
[[8]][[1]]
[1] "a" "d" "e"

[[8]][[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "f"


[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
[1] "a" "d" "f"

[[9]][[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "e"


[[10]]
[[10]][[1]]
[1] "a" "e" "f"

[[10]][[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: This has fixed it. Thank you!!

Comment: Why the call to `asplit`? Can't you simply use `simplify = FALSE` in the first `combn` as you did in the next one? Also, this could be a nice addition to the _more canonical_ question [Create Combinations in R by Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57732672/4408538)

Comment: Of course, much more consistent :) Not sure how my answer scale with multiple groups (here 2) and much more combinations