# A script that results in the most ideal composition of groups of people

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, scripting

I am organizing this activity for 60 people. These 60 people will be split into groups of 6 people per group. Each participant can provide a maximum of 3 other participants that they want to be group members with.

**How would you write a script that results in the most ideal composition of these 10 groups?**

I was thinking about appointing 2 points to each relationship with reciprocal preference and 1 point to one-sided preference.

Comment: Please explain why your approach might not be suitable and why you are looking for other suggestions

Comment: I think the approach of appointing numbers to relationships is logical, however I am not sure how to deal with the rest of the script. What will be the next steps after these points are given?

Comment: Here's a suggestion of how to proceed once you have decided how to calculate a score for a given group of people: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570039/whats-the-fastest-heuristic-algorithm-to-split-students-into-groups/34572278#34572278